# I am trying to solve a problem with in app scripts for a google workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu95M.png)I am looking to achieve an app script that will export a full row of information based on two arguments.

In the spreadsheet attached in the screenshot you will see that all yellow columns will be populated based on an intake form. What I am looking to do is test if column G has either "BPO", "VA" or "T". But I want to only run this if the checkbox in column H is true. If both arguments are true I want to export to a different page in the same workbook.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more detail. What do you mean by export a full row. Can you provide an example of the information that you have

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that. 

The new image you will see will show a couple new things:

There is a sheet for the three locations I want to short listed in front of the supervisor (VA, BPO, T). 

The IVA is for videos and IAD is for document so I need to sort by that as well.

The checkbox in column H is supposed to be an "are you sure" so if you select the wrong person from the dropdown in G that it wont send until the box is checked.

Ideally at that point it exports based on that criteria.

Comment: New image added to original post

Comment: Once the info is identified on which sheet it should go to I want that entire row of information from all columns to export to that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the query function in Google Sheets to complete this.

[Query Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)

The basic syntax is:

```
QUERY(Range of Data,select statement for your fields)
```

So in your instance in Cell A1 of each of your seperate sheets you would want

```
=query(Form!A:H,"Select * where G like 'VA%' and C like 'Video'",1)
```

You would then need to change the formula on each tab so that the two like elements match the criteria for that tab i.e. BPO and Video ect

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much! What function is best way to get this program to delete as it exports to other tabs?

Comment: With this function you wouldnt be able to delete the information from the first tab as it is only undertaking a query of the main information

Answer (score 0):

#### Export on meeting requirements

```
function elxporto() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheetname");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Export");
  const vs = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 2,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const g = ["BPO","VA","T"];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(g.some(e => r[6].includes(e)) && r[7] == 'TRUE') {
      osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, r.length).setValues(r);
      osh.deleteRow(i + 3 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```